# How to set a new username and password after starting the server in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have created a sign-up form and added users in the database . But i provide login facility using this piece of code which runs only when the server starts :

```
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {        
        List<UserEntity> userEntities=userService.getAll();
        for(UserEntity userEntity: userEntities) {
            RoleEntity roleEntity=roleService.getBy(userEntity.getRoleId());
            auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(userEntity.getUserName()).password(userEntity.getPassword()).roles(roleEntity.getDescription());
        }

    }
}
```

How to add new users in the configuration so that they can login without restarting the server ?

Comment: Are you using a in-memory database? May I ask why?

Comment: i am using mysql. I have to users in a controller .

Comment: Then why need authentication based on DAO. Check out this example : http://www.journaldev.com/2736/spring-mvc-security-example-using-in-memory-userdetailsservice-and-jdbc-authentication

Comment: I need to add users on the fly . I don't know about the DAO part .

Comment: The DAO stuff will read the users directly from your user table. So as soon as you add a new user in your database, he will be able to login. No need to maintain a separate in memory user cache.

Comment: Spring security is taking usernames and passwords only when the server starts . If a new user is added to the database after the server starts then there is no way for him to login without restarting the server. I want to know if I can add a new user that can be authenticated by spring security after the server starts.

Comment: Yes, if you want to do that, configure Spring Security to retrieve the users directly from the database. This is possible, see the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc

Comment: It worked thanks. I followed the link from this page .https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-4-authenticate-and-authorize-users

Answer (score 0):

Hook on the application start event and use it to add the users to your (InMemmory???) Database.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;    

@Component
public class DbInit implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    //This check is needed, because a typical web application has two contexts,
    //therefore it fires two ContextRefreshedEvent  on startup
    if (isFirstContextRefreshedEvent()) {
       // initYourDatabase
    }
  }

  private boolean done = false;

  /** Return true if this method in this bean is invoked the first time;
       else (second, third... invocation) false. */
  private synconized boolean isFirstContextRefreshedEvent() {
     if (!done) {
       done = false;
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  }  
}
```